# Automatically resize items when minimizing window

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello i'm working on a project and i got a problem.
My "items" (which are divs) get out of the container when i minimize my window.
My code is a bit weird but it's working so far, here's where are my items.

```
<div class="containerpage">
<div class="container">
    <div class="artcontainer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="post">
                            <div class="post-img-content">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/460x250/e67e22/ffffff&text=HTML5" class="img-responsive" />
                            <span class="post-title"><b>Make a Image Blur Effects With</b><br />
                            <b>CSS3 Blur</b></span>
                            </div>
                        <div class="content">
                        <div class="author">
                            By <b>Bhaumik</b> |
                            <time datetime="2014-01-20">January 20th, 2014</time>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
                            Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                            unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2014/01/jquery-highlight-table-row-and-column.html" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Same col-sm-4 col-md-4 several times on col-md-10 that make my "thumbnails"-->
                <div class="col-md-2">
                <!-- Image that you can see on the right -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now what i get when i minimize my window : https://i.stack.imgur.com/wid7y.jpg

As you can see my blocs (HTML5) are outside of the container, plus there's a grey space at the right that blocks another image (which is in the col-md-2), can this be from a margin or padding on the body or main part ?

Every other elements on the site automatically resize themselves but no this part, where is my mistake ? Is this from the CSS ?
I'd actually like my items not to be smaller when i minimize but instead having one by row automatically when minimizing.

-- Also i've always used col-md most of the times, is there an equivalence for smaller screens that i should precise when i make my col ?

I hope i've been clear enough (:

Comment: My friend can you please fiddle your code

Comment: your solution is Provide width in % not in pixel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve spacing between columns using the col-xs-* classes,within in a  col-xs-* div coded below. The spacing is consistent so that all of your columns line up correctly. To get even spacing and column size I would do the following:

**( Note : You can Use col-xs-* or col-md-* or col-sm-* . i used col-xs-*)**

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
            <div class="col-md-12 well">
                Some Content..
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
            <div class="col-md-12 well">
                Some Second Content..
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
            <div class="col-md-12 well">
                Some Second Content..
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
            <div class="col-md-12 well">
                Some Second Content..
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
            <div class="col-md-12 well">
                Some Second Content..
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
            <div class="col-md-12 well">
                Some Second Content..
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
            <div class="col-md-12 well">
                Some Second Content..
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
            <div class="col-md-12 well">
                Some Second Content..
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following line to your css class for the DIV elements:

```
display: inline-block;
```

This should make the DIVs to go down a row if they don't have enough room.

Answer (score 0):

Great Keval Bhatt, i changed width px to % and it worked almost perfectly !

I also tried display: inline-block; but when i minimized, my items were "behind" the container so they disappeared.
Changing px to % worked, thanks again ! (: